# How can I set the y axis limit?

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization, subplot, yaxis

I am comparing the training accuracies of two different neural networks. How can I set the scales so that they are comparable. (like setting both y axis to 1 for both so that the graphs are comparable)

The code I used is below:

```
 def NeuralNetwork(X_train, Y_train, X_val, Y_val, epochs, nodes, lr):
        hidden_layers = len(nodes) - 1
        weights = InitializeWeights(nodes)
        Training_accuracy=[]
        Validation_accuracy=[]
        for epoch in range(1, epochs+1):
            weights  = Train(X_train, Y_train, lr, weights)
    
            if (epoch % 1 == 0):
                print("Epoch {}".format(epoch))
                print("Training Accuracy:{}".format(Accuracy(X_train, Y_train, weights)))
                
                if X_val.any():
                    print("Validation Accuracy:{}".format(Accuracy(X_val, Y_val, weights)))
                Training_accuracy.append(Accuracy(X_train, Y_train, weights))
                Validation_accuracy.append(Accuracy(X_val, Y_val, weights))
        plt.plot(Training_accuracy) 
        plt.plot((Validation_accuracy),'#008000') 
        plt.legend(["Training_accuracy", "Validation_accuracy"])    
        plt.xlabel("Epoch")
        plt.ylabel("Accuracy")  
        return weights , Training_accuracy , Validation_accuracy
```

and the two graphs are as below :

[image]

Comment: if you are using subplots you can also write ``sharey=True``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try use matplotlib.pyplot.ylim(low, high) refer this link https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/matplotlib-pyplot-ylim-in-python/

Answer (score 4):

You could use `fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2)` to build a subplot with 1 row and 2 columns ([reference](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html)).

### Basic Code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(16)
a = np.random.rand(10)
b = np.random.rand(10)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2)

ax[0].plot(a)
ax[1].plot(b)

plt.show()
```

[image]

If you set `sharey = 'all'` parameter, all subplots you created will share the same scale for y axis:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharey = 'all')
```

[image]

Finally, you can manually set limits for y axis with `ax[0].set_ylim(0, 1)`.

### Complete Code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(16)
a = np.random.rand(10)
b = np.random.rand(10)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharey = 'all')

ax[0].plot(a)
ax[1].plot(b)

ax[0].set_ylim(0, 1)

plt.show()
```

[image]